# PHP foreach on nested array ($_POST)

Tags: php, arrays

I have an order form that uses the same name for each row item, an example below:

```
<input name="item['1']['stock_code']">
<input name="item['1']['quantity']">

<input name="item['2']['stock_code']">
<input name="item['2']['quantity']">
```

I am iterating over each of the $_POST item's like so:

```
$items = $_POST['item'];

foreach($items as $item){

    $item_stock_code = $item['stock_code'];
    $item_description = $item['description'];
    $item_price_net = $item['sale_price'];
    $item_quantity = $item['quantity'];
    $item_notes = $item['order_notes'];

}
```

However, I am now receiving an error when trying to access each property of an undefined index.

An example of `print_r($item)` is below:

```
Array
(
    ['stock_code'] => PLN-10002J
    ['quantity'] => 2
    ['description'] => 5MM-20MM TRANSFER CENTRE PUNCH (PLN-10002J)
    ['sale_price'] => 24.35
    ['order_notes'] => testt
)
```

Where am I going wrong, trying to access the values of each item?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @u_mulder... `Notice: Undefined index: stock_code ` is the error, along with the same for description, sale_price, quantity and order_notes.

Comment: Are you sure that error related to `foreach` loop?

Comment: @u_mulder... Yes, the line it says the error is on ties up with the `foreach` loop

Comment: @mario... Can you please submit that as an answer please? Removing the single quotes has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form names contain single quotes around the keys like that:

```
<input name="item['1']['stock_code']">
<input name="item['1']['quantity']">
```

Then PHP will retain them as *literal* array keys, including the quotes.
So you had to access entries with:

```
#              ↓        ↓
$_POST["'1'"]["'stock_id'"]
// Notice the double/single quote combos.
```

So, yes, it's best to remove the `'` quotes from the the form field names=, so PHP constructs standard array keys.